# After login navigation not working due to fetch async in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

After successful login using the fetch call, when I try to navigate to an explorer view using
    self.props.history.push('/explore');

it appears that it works only sometimes due to async nature of fetch.
Even when it works, it navigates back to login back after momentarily flashing the explorer view.
What is the right way to do this?
Thanks

If I put an alert after the fetch …. alert("Done")
in the code, it does flash or stay at explorer view, before routing back to login view.

```
class login extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      loggedIn: false
    };

    this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleEmailChange  = event => {
      this.setState({email: event.target.value});
  }

  handlePasswordChange  = event => {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value});
  }

    onClick = ({ event, props }) => 
    { 
      alert('on login');
      // alert("EMail: " + this.state.email);

      const self = this;
      fetch('http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/login/', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              username: this.state.email,
              password: this.state.password         
          })
      })
      .then(function(response){
        //console.log(response);
        //alert(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
          var obj = myJson.success;
          console.log(obj);
          if(obj == true)
          {
            self.props.history.push('/explore');
          }
          self.setState({ loggedIn: myJson.success});
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson.data));
        });
      alert('Done ');
    }

   render() {

    return (
      <div className="login"  >
      <div class="loginBox" >
        <form>
        <p>Email</p>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange}></input>
        <p>Password</p>
        <input type="password" name="" placeholder="***********" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}></input>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Sign In" onClick={this.onClick}></input>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling function in render?? Event like this should be called outside render. It will  create every time function new copy whenever it renders.

Comment: As shown in the edited code above I moved the onclick() out of the render(). The behavior is still the same. The login page flashes and displays login page again after login. It only navigates to the explore page if I wait 2 seconds on alert "on login" and another 2 seconds on "done" alert. Only 3 weeks since I started  reactjs. So there must be something pretty basic that I am missing here.

Comment: I removed the form tag in the login and the problem went away. Presence of the form tag was causing the app to be rerendered. And on app rerender the login was being rerendered.So even though fetch was success ful the navigation to explore page was sporadic. Why the form tag causes this issue, i dont know. But for now i am know. Thanks to all respondents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you declare the function onclick outside the render method. The onclick function exists only in the context of the render, each time the inputs or states of the composite muten are recreated. Also that the actions as calls to api declare them in a container and that the function passes as property to the Login component.

Answer (score 0):

First of all move fetch to `componentDidMount` and its better not to use `history.push('/explore');` instead of it store a variable and depending on it redirect by returning `<Redirect />` in render.
https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a